# Make ListView scrollabe when keyboard appears with adjustPan

Tags: android, listview

In my android app I have `ListView` with `EditTexts` in it. I must use `adjustPan` to not lose text selecting after long click but I want to make `ListView` scrollable when keyboard appears.

So with `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` it looks like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZkOs.png)

selected text is under keyboard and `listview` is not scrollable.

With only `adjustPan` it looks like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5alT3.png)

Selected text is visible but bar with copy,cut buttons scrolling up out from layout visible part.

With only `adjustResize` everything is perfect besides that after long click text is getting selected only for 1 second and then losing focus.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android.support.v7.appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_open_entry"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d9d9d9"
tools:context="com.example.david.boom.openEntry">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android.support.v7.appcompat:title="Entry"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android.support.v7.appcompat:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
    android.support.v7.appcompat:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"/>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#d9d9d9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:divider="@drawable/transparent_color"
    android:id="@+id/entry_list">
</ListView>
```

Comment: try stateHidden

Comment: Same as with `adjustResize`, text losing selection.

Comment: try to use both

Comment: No, still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to include `windowSoftInputMode` to your menifest file. For example:

try adding this:

```
<activity android:name="..."
      ...
      ...
      android:windowSoftInputMode=""adjustPan|adjustResize">
...
/>
```

**EDIT:**

Then try including your RelativeLayout inside the scrollView. Like this:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillViewport="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:weightSum="1.0" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:id="@+id/l_layout">

    <ListView android:"...">
    ...
    </ListView>



</RelativeLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was talking right about this, without adjustPan text losing selection.

Comment: So with adjustPan and adjustResize it looks like this: 1

selected text is under keyboard and listview is not scrollable.

Comment: you have listView inside scrollView ?

Comment: I noticed some strange behaviour, `adjustPan` needed for text selecting only on devices where copy button appear like bar on the top of layout.

Comment: No, listview inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: Without `adjustPan` I can't select text, with `adjustPan` layout not scrolling, the only way to not use it is to place `ListView` inside Linear or Relative layout and set isScrollContainer to false but in this case copy bar still going up so I need to add adjustResize but now text become not selectable again.